# Is wp_kses the right approach in sanitizing this string?

Tags: security, sanitization

I have a function that trims my post title and I escape the final output using `wp_kses`.

Is this the right approach?

```
function theTrimmedPostTitle( $length = BIG_INT, $delimiter = '' )
{
    $title = get_the_title();
    $url = esc_url( get_permalink() );

    if( $length > 0 ) {
        $trimmed_title = mb_strimwidth( $title, 0, $length, '' );
        $title = $trimmed_title . ( strlen( $title ) > strlen( $trimmed_title ) ? $delimiter : '' );
    }

    $title_string = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" rel="bookmark">%s</a>',
        $url,
        $title
    );

    $escaped_title = wp_kses(
        $title_string,
        $allowed_html = [
            'a' => [
                'href' => [],
                'rel' => [],
            ]
        ]
    );

    return $escaped_title;
}
```

Another thought would be that since I'm building my string with `$title_string` where I specifically say what my output must be, doesn't it make more sense to have it there instead of after?

Additionally, if my post title contains `<div>`, it doesn't get output, but this could be problematic for plugins that do insert HTML on the title and also for say, programming bloggers - that `<div>` that was meant as a string is now not displayed.

So I was thinking, how about I `esc_html` the title itself?

```
$title_string = sprintf(
    '<a href="%s" rel="bookmark">%s</a>',
    esc_url( $url ),
    esc_html( $title )
);

$escaped_title = wp_kses(
    $title_string,
    $allowed_html = [
        'a' => [
            'href' => [],
            'rel' => [],
        ]
    ]
);
```

Of course, I understand that I'm pulling the title which is already sanitized by WordPress itself, but *cough* a few markets have certain requirements which make no sense, so I have to do this.